# ElasticSearch Hosted on AWS by ES to pandas df and back to ES ConnectionError

Tags: pandas, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

[image: JN Error]

[image: Kibana]

[image: Indecis]

I just started with ElasticSearch, and took free 14 days trial from [here.](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service)

Got an `username`, `password` and `id`, now I am passing my elasticsearch host `url`, `username` and `password`. But getting Error. How can I retrieve dataframe from elasticsearch to pandas from `AWS` hosted `ES`.
I wan't process this and save it back to ES, i.e. to same index as well in a new Index after processing it.
Also if I look at `/_cat/indices?v` it exists there. 
What I did is used logstash to push MySql (hosted on AWS) to ES (as well hosted on AWS) Now I want to get data, process it and push back to ElasticSearch. Like am forming Apriori (Market Basket Analysis) from transaction. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection Shall be like:

```
es = Elasticsearch(host="yourhost.aws.found.io",
port="9243", scheme="https",
http_auth=('elastic', 'password'))
```

The Elastic Search Add `http://` and port as `9200` **if not passed as default** , which results into wrong host as:

```
http://https://yourhost:yourport:9200
https://yourhost:youport  --rather than this
```

And then to `ConnectionError`. Where as my host was on `https://` with `s` and on different port.

Worked for me!

[image: Solution]